# void (*foo)(void) : meaning of latest (void)

Tags: c, void

B.A.T.M.A.N./A.L.F.R.E.D. OpenMesh project:

[function read_answer](http://git.open-mesh.org/alfred.git/blob/HEAD:/vis/vis.c#l748) instantiates a pointer to a type [struct vis_print_ops](http://git.open-mesh.org/alfred.git/blob/HEAD:/vis/vis.c#l715) that is defined

```
struct vis_print_ops
{
    void (*preamble)(void);
    void (*interfaces)(uint8_t iface_n, struct vis_iface *ifaces);
    void (*entries)(uint8_t entries_n, struct vis_entry *vis_entries,
            uint8_t iface_n, struct vis_iface *ifaces);
    void (*postamble)(void);
};
```

Now look at

```
void (*preamble)(void)
```

could you please tell me what is the meaning of the last (void)?  Isn't

```
void (*preamble)
```

enough?

Comment: It essentialy means it's a function pointer with no parameters.

Answer (score 5):

The last `void` means that there are no arguments in function that will be pointed by `preamble`.

`void (*preamble)` isn't enough because this is only a pointer to void whereas `void (*preamble)(void)` is a function pointer.

Comment: Would `void (*preamble)()` be okay?

Comment: @Caterpillar, no, that is not the same. It means that `preamble` takes some undefined arguments.

Answer (score 5):

It means that your declaring a function pointer with no parameters. It's not more complicated than that. It is similiar to something like:
`int main(void)`
and
`int main()`

Both are the same. Be careful though as discussed in the comments, if you declare a function pointer without the void keyword and only the empty brackets it specifies a function pointer with undefined arguments.

Comment: @cad Correct, I edited my answer. Thanks!